# Java Web Start can't find jar with formatted version filename

Tags: java, web-applications, versioning, java-web-start

I have simple-as-can-be Web Start application sitting on a file server. The directory consists of the following:

```
foo__V1.1.jar
runfoo.jnlp
```

The contents of `runfoo.jnlp` is as follows:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <jnlp spec="1.0+" href="http://myserver.com/runfoo.jnlp" codebase="http://myserver.com">
  <information>
    <title>Foo</title>
  </information>
  <security>
    <all-permissions/>
  </security>
  <resources>
    <j2se version="1.7.0_06+" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se" />
    <jar href="foo.jar" main="true" version="1.0+"/>
    <property name="jnlp.versionEnabled" value="true"/>
  </resources>
  <application-desc name="Foo" main-class="com.myserver.foo.Foo" width="640" height="480" />
  <update check="always" policy="always" />
</jnlp>
```

The issue is that Web Start is attempting to access a file at http://myserver.com/runfoo.jnlp?version-id=1.0%2B, and not finding it.

I assume there's some extra step required to have Web Start automatically grab the latest jar version in this simple instance, but after a lot of Googling all I've found is the same steps over and over:

- rename file to `<file_name>__V<versionnumber>.jar`
- Add the `versionEnabled` property to the jnlp
- enjoy versioned goodness

The jnlp file runs absolutely fine when I specify an explicit file name, but always fails when I've tried to implement versioning.

I'm sure I'm **missing something vital** but I haven't been able to find it anywhere. I'm guessing that although my set-up is simple, it's not simple-as-can-be-and-also-work.

Any help will be much appreciated :)

---

The explicit exception is:

```
com.sun.deploy.net.FailedDownloadException: Unable to load resource: (http://myserver.com/foo.jar?version-id=1.0%2B, 1.0+)
```

I've also tried removing the `+` from the version specification and the same error occurs (apart from a missing plus of course). Writting `foo__V1.1.jar` in the jnlp file works but of course defeats the whole point of this.

Comment: That JNLP is invalid.  Be sure to check it using [JaNeLA](http://pscode.org/janela/).

Comment: Thanks, the un-closed update element was a typo but the invalid attributes in the application-desc were there erroneously - thanks for the heads up. It's interesting that the JNLP started fine despite these errors - especially the fact that the un-closed update element made it invalid XML.

Comment: *"It's interesting that the JNLP started fine despite these errors"*  The JWS client does not reject invalid JNLP files, but tries to guess what was meant.  I think that is an extremely bad idea - [GI/GO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_in,_garbage_out).  How two different versions of the client might parse the invalid information is anyone's guess.  :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The versioned file names are a convention used by the [JNLP download servlet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/downloadservletguide.html) to know what to serve when the client asks for `lib.jar?version=something`. You need the download servlet on the server side (or you need to duplicate its behaviour in `mod_rewrite` rules or similar), just the plain files with versions names is not enough.

Comment: I honestly never read anything that explicitly said 'all these versioning conventions are only valid if you're using a JNLP download servlet', so thankyou :)

Comment: To complete the automation, you can generate the JNLP file using PHP or similar.

Answer (score 0):

For followers, a similar issue for me

```
java.io.IOException: Error returned: 10 Could not locate resource
    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.actionDownload(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.downloadResource(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.getResource(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.getResource(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.LaunchDownload$DownloadTask.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

"unable to launch application"

```
com.sun.deploy.net.FailedDownloadException: Unable to load resource: (http://host:port/webapp_name/app/jar-name.jar?version-id=1.5.0-20160707.182810-19, 1.5.0-20160707.182810-19)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.actionDownload(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.downloadResource(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.getResource(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.getResource(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.LaunchDownload$DownloadTask.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

meant "the special internal file version.xml didn't match up right with the filenames deployed and existent in the web-app directory":

ref: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/downloadservletguide.html